# X.509 Certificate not found in server certificate store

Tags: .net, cryptography

I am trying to get a certificate in the certificate store. I is working fine locally using the following code (debug) but when deployed to server (release) does not work. I have tried with CurrentUser as well at the server.

The certificate is installed in the same location in my local machine and server.

```
private X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate(string certificateId)
{
    StoreLocation storeLocation;
#if DEBUG
    storeLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
#else
    storeLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
#endif
    var userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, storeLocation);
    try
    {
        userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        var certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates;
        var certs = certificatesInStore.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectKeyIdentifier,
            certificateId, true);
        X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
        if (certs.Count > 0)
        {
            clientCertificate = certs[0];
        }
        else
        {
            var message = $"Certificate {certificateId} not found!";
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
        return clientCertificate;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        userCaStore.Close();
    }
}
```

If anyone has any idea how to figure this, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `certificateId` is different on the machines. You should probably take a closer look at the certs using Certificate Manager MSC snapin. I *think* `certutil` will allow you to dump certs from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found couple of things working differently at the server:

Instead of pro grammatically getting from the store, I exported the certificate from the store and embedded the exported .cer certificate file as a resource in visual studio. However even that did not work in the server. Then instead of using .cer file, I embedded the .p12 file and after that the problem was solved.